# Simple, stoppable Timer using Raku concurrency

Tags: concurrency, raku

I have been wrestling with Promises, Supplies and other concurrency features, but I can't get find a straightforward way to do what I want.

My goal is to do something like this:

```
class Timer {
    has $.promise;
    has $.counter is default(0);

    method start {
        $!promise = Promise.new;

        loop {
            $!counter++;
            self.show;
        }
    }   

    method stop {
        $!promise.break;
    }   

    method reset {
        $!counter = Nil;
        self.show;
    }

    method show {
        say "timer: $!counter";
    }   
}

my Timer $t .= new;
$t.start;
$t.stop;
$t.reset;
```

Of course, this doesn't work because the loop will run to infinity and we will never proceed to $t.stop.

So, please can you advise me on how to bring Raku concurrency into the picture to make this do what I would like?

Comment: What is the interval that you want the counter to show?  Or do you want it to run as fast as possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would be my basic `Timer` class.  It takes a single `:display` argument, which must be a `Callable` doing the display.

Note that the [`start`](https://docs.raku.org/language/control#start) control statement is used to start the concurrency.  Inside it, there is just a loop which calls the display logic until the loop condition becomes false.  Which you can do with calling the `.stop` method.

```
class Timer {
    has &.display is required;
    has Bool $!running;

    method start(Timer:D: --> Nil) {
        $!running = True;
        start {
            &!display() while $!running;
        }
    }

    method stop(Timer:D: --> Nil) {
        $!running = False;
    }
}

sub display() {
    state $count;
    print (++$count).fmt('%6d') ~ "\b" x 6;
}

my $timer = Timer.new(:&display);

$timer.start;

sleep 5;

$timer.stop;
```

Comment: ah - thanks @lizmat - that is just exactly what I had envisaged... I want a 1sec tick so I can just put ```sleep 1;``` in the display sub. don't ask me why I couldn't assemble that from the raku concurrency docs since that is pretty much what they say...!